# Bind <form> inputs, to totally different model than model on view. Tricky question or my mistake in design?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

This problem requires big description to get it right, but i'm really struggling with that, and i will be really grateful for any help.

So: Let's say, that we have got a view, let's call it "House", which has got a house details, below we have got a list of people scheduled to inspect a house, and a form, in which user can make a new appointment for that house inspection.
On that view, we have got a @model HouseDto:

```
public class HouseDto
{
  public Guid HouseId {get; set;}
  public HouseInfo HouseInfo {get; set;} //contains info about house, not important in that case
  public List<Appointment> Appointments {get; set;} //contains dates, username, actual appointment content, etc - it does not matter in that case
}
```

So as You can see, on the view we are just having basic data about the house in HouseInfo field of Dto, and list of Appointments, to show them to a user. But, we also need to be able to make a new appointment on that view.
For that, we can use a simple form:

```
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Appointments" asp-action="CreateAppointment">
      <input type="hidden" name="houseId" value="@Model.HouseId" />
      <div class="form-group mt-2">
          <label for="note">Add a new appointment:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="appointmentContent" rows="2" required style="resize:none"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-2">Add</button>
    </form>
```

And in a controller, we have got an action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAppointment(Guid houseId, string appointmentContent)
```

And - it is working indeed. But, the thing is, that if i understood correctly, it is wrong to pass raw data to controller, and i should use something like "CreateAppointmentRequest", so that the action will look like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAppointment(CreateAppointmentRequest cr)
```

And the CreateAppointmentRequest will look like this (reflection of form on "House" view):

```
public class CreateAppointmentRequest
{
  public Guid houseId {get; set;}
  public string appointmentContent {get; set;}
}
```

The thing is - that i don't really know, how to do that, since i do not have that model in my view, so i cannot bind  values to that model.

So i see two options, and both are wrong:

a) Just add an CreateAppointmentRequest field to my HouseDto. Which is wrong, because, the only thing that i will be able to achieve with that, is to send whole HouseDto (with CreateAppointmentRequest inside) to my CreateAppointment action. Well, it is not what i am looking for, since in CreateAppointment i don't need a whole Dto - only CreateAppointmentRequest is needed.

b) Create a partial view, for showing list of Appointments and for creating new Appointment.
But, in that case, i will need to create a new Dto:

```
public class AppointmentDto
{
  public List<Appointment> appointments {get; set;} //for showing scheduled appointments
  public CreateAppointmentRequest createRequest {get; set;} //for creating new one
}
```

The problem with this approach, is that i will need to render that partial view on my main (House) view, so i will need to pass the model to this partial view, maybe like that:

```
@Html.Partial("_AppointmentsPartial", new AppointmentDto{ appointments = @Model.Appointments, createRequest = new CreateAppointmentRequest() }
```

Which leads me to the same problem - on that _AppointmentsPartial i will need to pass whole AppointmentDto to the CreateAppointment action, and i want to pass to that action only the CreateAppointmentRequest model.

To be honest, i don't even have any idea how to do that, and searching for similar problems does result in nothing. Any help would be much appreciated

PS - Whole code for that post was written "by hand" in post creator form on Stack, due to the fact that my actual application is too much complicated for describing it here, so sorry for any simple mistakes.

PPS - **This question is posted mostly because i want to implement MediatR, and the matter described in this post is blocking me of doing that, since MediatR requires queries and commands, and not controller actions with some plain parameters like string, int, etc.**

Answer (score 0):

What you did in the first place was not wrong. The parameter received in the controller is not only a model class, it can be a string, a number, etc. If you only need these two fields: `houseId, appointmentContent` and do not want to accept other fields, then you can only pass these two parameters:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAppointment(Guid houseId, string appointmentContent)
```

It's no problem.

If you must receive a model class, since the model you use in View is `HouseDto`, `HouseDto` does not only contain two fields `HouseId` and `appointmentContent`, so you have to pass the entire Dto model to get the two fields you want.

You can check this link: [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Ok. So with that approach, that passing multiple parameters, instead of createrequest to action, how can i implement MediatR in here?
Next question - Is passing whole Dto to action OK?

Comment: No, it's not a replacement for create request to `action`. According to your code, you need `action` to receive some parameters and process them, but you don't need to receive the entire model.

Comment: About implementing MediatR, you can refer to [this link](https://medium.com/dotnet-hub/use-mediatr-in-asp-net-or-asp-net-core-cqrs-and-mediator-in-dotnet-how-to-use-mediatr-cqrs-aspnetcore-5076e2f2880c). I'd rather recommend that you republish a post describing your exact needs as this is not your original question.